# when gitbook init there are error Error loading version latest

Tags: node.js, npm, gitbook

When I follow [this](https://toolchain.gitbook.com/setup.html#) instructions , step by step

- mac OS 10.13
- nodejs v8.7.0
- npm 5.5.1
- CLI version: 2.3.1
- GitBook version: 3.2.3

Finally get this "gitbook init" error:

> Error loading version latest: Error: Cannot find module 'extend'
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
>  at
>   Function.Module._load (module.js:476:23)
>  at Module.require
>   (module.js:568:17)
>  at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>  at
>   Object.
>   (/Users/jinlei/.gitbook/versions/3.2.3/lib/index.js:1:76)
>  at
>   Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
>  at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
>  at Module.load
>   (module.js:545:32)
>  at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
>  at
>   Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
>  
>  TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'commands' of null

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj0Ji.png)

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the LTS version of node and npm (6.11.4 and 3.10.10 respectively), that worked for me.